# build a topology with $ X = \{a,b,c,d,e,f \} $

Tags: general-topology

I need to build a topology with $  X = \{a,b,c,d,e,f \} $ but I have very clear how? 
there are so many elements.
I know the properties of topological spaces, but not how 
anyone know how? 
is not well identify sets that can give me a topology.

I tried with:

$\{X,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$ and $\{X,\emptyset\}$ but I don't know.

What is the minimal topology of $X$?

Comment: The first one is not a topology because the finite union of open sets must be open. So $\{a\}\cup \{b\}=\{a,b\}$ must be open. The second one works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example of a set that is not a topology when $X=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$
$$\mathcal{O}=\{X,\emptyset \{a\}\{c,d\}\{a,c,e\}\{b ,c,d\}\}$$
$\mathcal{O}$ is not a topology on $X$ because the union of $\{c,d\}\cup \{a,c,e\}=\{a,c,d,e\}$ does not belong to $\mathcal{O}$ 
Here you have some examples of topologies if $X=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$
Minimal Topology :
 $$\mathcal{T}_a=\{X,\emptyset , \{a\}\}$$
$$\mathcal{T}_b=\{X,\emptyset , \{b\}\}$$
$$\mathcal{T}_c=\{X,\emptyset , \{c\}\}$$
And

$$\mathcal{T}=\{X,\emptyset , \{a\}\{c,d\}\{a,c,d\}\{b,c,d,e,f\}\}$$. Then  $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology because satisfies all the conditions of topology

Comment: I don't know what definition of minimal topology you are using, but in the sense that the topology should contain the least number of sets, it should be the trivial topology, $\{\varnothing, X\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The properties of a topology $\tau$ on a space $X$ are as follows:

1. $X\in \tau$ and $\emptyset \in \tau$ (the whole space and the empty set are open sets in $X$).
2. If $U\in \tau$ and $V\in \tau$, then $U\cap V \in \tau$ (finite intersection of open sets are open).
3. If $\mathcal F \subseteq \tau$, then $\bigcup_{U\in \mathcal F}U \in \tau$ (arbitrary unions of open sets are open).

In your first example you have $\{a\} \in \tau$ and $\{b\} \in \tau$, but their union, $\{a, b\}$ is not in $\tau$. therefore this cannot be a topology.

Your second example $\tau = \{X, \emptyset\}$ will be a topology for any space $X$. It is the simplest topology allowed, and it is therefore called the *trivial* topology.

The following topology also has a name: $\tau = \{U \mid U \subseteq X\}$, containing *all* subsets of $X$. It is called the *discrete* topology. Another valid topology is $\tau = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{U \mid a \in U\}$ where a set is open iff it contains $a$ or is the empty set.

All in all there are a lot of different topologies on your $X$. If you want to make your own example, do this: Start with a few subsets, containing $X$ and $\emptyset$ (this starting point is called a sub-basis for the resulting topology). Now add to your collection all possible intersections of your sets (only intersections between finitely many sets are allowed, but that makes little difference when the set itself is finite) (what you now have is called a *basis* for the topology you end up with). Then append all possible unions of those sets again. You now have a full-fledged topology on your space.